# EF Migration migrate to 0 call initial creates down

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to figure out the syntax to bring migrations down to an empty database as in call the down method on the inital create migration.  Does anyone know the proper syntax to call the Down method in a migration something akin to this:

```
Update-Database -StartupProjectName "Infrastructure.Data" -TargetMigration 0
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx suggests it's "Update-Database –TargetMigration:$InitialDatabase"  does that not work for you?

Comment: I tried using $InitialDatabase but it doesn't work. Using 0 does! At least with EF v5.0

Comment: Note that this will undo the changes made by migrations, which doesn't necessarily mean an empty database.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
update-database -startupproject someproject -targetmigration 0
```

That will bring you back to a completely empty database.

I assembled a [complete reference](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/) to the package manager commands for ef migrations.