# Scripting Initial Migration with Entity Framework Migrations

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I'm having trouble making Entity Framework update to the latest migration automatically (conflicts between SimpleMembership and the EF data model) so I've decided to script each migration to SQL then apply that.

However I've run into a problem with introducing the first migration. I have a full migration in my project that I generated by running `Add-Migration <migration name>` and now I'd like to create a SQL script using `Update-Database -Script`. However when I run that command EF checks my code and the development database, sees that everything is up to date and doesn't script a new migration. I thought I could use the `-SourceMigration` switch, but that appears to require a migration *before* the one you want to reach.

I could simply delete the development database, script the migration, then rerun Add-Migration, but I feel like I must be mistaken in how I'm using migrations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not really undocumented:
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621 or [EF Migration migrate to 0 call initial creates down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996576/ef-migration-migrate-to-0-call-initial-creates-down)

The proper usage should be something like be "Update-Database –SourceMigration:$InitialDatabase ..." or "Update-Database –SourceMigration:0" for shorter syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an undocumented solution. Instead of passing a migration name to `-SourceMigration` simply pass 0 which and you'll get the migrations from before the initial migration.